# Matplotlib x-axis dynamic range update

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts

I've been trying to create a matplotlib animation with `FuncAnimation`.

The code below creates a simple animated line chart.

If this code runs all day (let's suppose it's tracking a stock price), chart will become too loaded with data and it won't be readable at all. (see attached image) To overcome this problem I was trying to update the x-axis dynamically as below so that the start of the x axis is increased by a value in every iteration but I can't get it to work.

Here is the line that causes the error:

`plt.axes().set_xlim([index,100])`

And the full code:

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import count
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

random.seed(234324234234)

x = []
y = []

plt.style.use("fivethirtyeight")

index = count()

def animate(i):
    x.append(next(index))
    y.append(random.randint(0,3))

    plt.cla()
    plt.plot(x,y)
    #plt.axes().set_xlim([index,100])

ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, interval=1000)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Image: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve this by adding `pyplot.xlim` method to your function (`pyplot.ylim` as well if needed). `Xlim` and `ylim` methods are used to define lower and upper limits of axes for **matplotlib pyplot charts**.

Dynamically updating axes:

If you define arguments of `xlim` with a constant your axes will be fixed but your Python code is specifically suitable to use the iterator `i` as the upper and/or lower limit value of `xlim`. For example:

```
def animate(i):
    x.append(next(index))
    y.append(random.randint(0,3))

    plt.cla()
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.xlim(i-20, i+10)
```

Just adjust the values to subtract and add as these values will define the margin before and after your most recent data point on the chart regarding x-axis.

Using the same technique you can also create a dynamically moving y-axis with including `ylim` in your function.

You can use both the example above and directly apply `xlim` to the plot figure as:

```
plt.xlim(i-20, i+10)
```

You can also use the axes method such as:

```
axes.set_xlim(i-20, i+10)
```

Source: [Matplotlib Example with Dynamic Axis](https://holypython.com/python-visualization-tutorial/guide-to-python-animations-animating-line-charts/#example3)

Official Matplotlib API Documentation: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlim.html

Comment: Wow, Thank you so much Zach! This solves my problem indeed. Never thought about using the iterator variable to control axes values for range. Thanks again!